# Does the recently-tested Russian hypersonic craft enter space?

Tags: russia, weapon

I am not going to invoke the K-word in this question!

Hypersonic long-range craft have to fly pretty high to travel circa mach 20. Would they need to travel into space to do so efficiently?

Comment: I agree, this better adressed as a meta question because it deals with topicality, especially when it comes to weaponry.

Comment: @Paul this is the ninth question to use the `weapon` tag so I don't think that's an issue at all. Lots of early rockets were "dual use" roughly speaking. As for dealing with topicality, I can just remove that part, so now it doesn't.

Comment: Which demarcation are you using as your criterion for judging what is space and what isn’t?  Ultimately, your question can’t be answered without some standard for comparison.

Comment: @Paul answers are able to choose their own. There are two reasons I'm avoiding the "K-word" One is that the demarcation of space is both fuzzy and in a state of flux ([Why is FAI considering lowering the K@$%@# Line to 80km?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32829/12102)) and the other is that there has been such K-related angst in the site that I'm going to give the word a pass this time. I think predictions that the my question can't be answered [are greatly exaggerated](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Mark-Twain-say-The-rumours-of-my-death-have-been-greatly-exaggerated) Let's see how it goes

Comment: It’s important to formulate the question such that it has a canonical answer.  As it stands, it doesn’t. It solicits a range of possible answers based on a range of possible demarcations.

Comment: Can you provide any reference to the craft under discussion?

Comment: Also, [apophasis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis) much?

Comment: Does this recently tested craft have a name? I'm unfamiliar with it and it's hard to search for it without a moniker, even if it's in Russian that's fine. Also, +1 for censoring the Kerbal Line, I have no idea why it has become so controversial but I am sick of reading about it heh. (+1 because I want to know more too)

Comment: The Uhoh Limit has been invoked!

Comment: @RussellBorogove [orbital elements of apophasis](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32985/12102) ;-)

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn [K-word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) and [craft](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/russia-is-poised-to-add-a-new-hypersonic-nuclear-warhead-to-its-arsenal/2018/12/26/e9b89374-0934-11e9-8942-0ef442e59094_story.html)

Comment: (The K-word part of my comment was entirely a joke) - The craft part however, was legit. Thanks for the link hah.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I had a hunch you were being humorous, but my "ASCII humor interpreter" is still a bit buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICBM’s don’t typically fly at hypersonic speeds for the entire duration of their flight. They do typically cruise at altitudes above 100km to take advantage of reduced drag, but they do so without engines turned on.  They follow suborbital trajectories with velocities that decrease up to apoapsis and increase upon reentry.  This particular missile (avangard hypersonic missile) uses a supersonic combustion ramjet engine (scramjet), which would not work in high knudsen flow (rarefied gas dynamics).  So while it won’t accelerate while in space, it can accelerate to suborbital trajectories that traverse space.

Cruise Missiles, on the other hand, usually stay well below 100km in altitude. But they don’t tend to travel at hypersonic speeds either. It would be interesting to know the actual altitude that the missile flies at, but I suspect there may be a strategic reason for not disclosing it publicly.

Comment: Is there enough air around and above 100 km for operation of a scramjet engine?

Comment: This one is more similar to a Cruise missile though.

Comment: @Uwe:  According to [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44837/what-is-the-highest-operational-ceiling-for-an-air-breathing-jet-engine), no.

Comment: @S.F., if it is truly a cruise missile, then it wouldn’t go any where near 100km.